# Language special chars normalize for ansi

Tags: c#, special-characters, ansi

I need to manage multiple European languages and I can't use utf-8 but only ansi.

I ask if there is a way to find the ansi equivalent for special chars of European languages:

Here a example of equivalent tables:

```
Italian

à = a'
è = e'
ì = i'
ò = o'
ù = u'

Spanish

á = ‘ + a
é = ‘ + e
í = ‘ + i
ó = ‘ + o
ú = ‘ + u
ñ = ~ + n
ü = ” + u
¡ = Alt (hold down) + !
¿ = Alt (hold down) + ?

German

Ä   Uppercase Umlaut (A)
Ö   Uppercase Umlaut (O)
Ü   Uppercase Umlaut (U)
ß   Eszett          (ss)
ä   Lowercase Umlaut (a)
ö   Lowercase Umlaut (o)
ü   Lowercase Umlaut (u)


French

À   Uppercase Accent Grave (A)
Â   Uppercase Accent Circonflex (A)
Ä   Uppercase Accent Tréma (A)
Æ   Uppercase Ligature(AE)
Ç   Uppercase Cedilla (C)
È   Uppercase Accent Grave (E)
É   Uppercase Accent Aigu (E)
Ê   Uppercase Accent Circonflex (E)
Ë   Uppercase Accent Tréma (E)
Î   Uppercase Accent Circonflex (I)
Ï   Uppercase Accent Tréma (I)
Ô   Uppercase Accent Circonflex (O)
Œ   Uppercase Ligature(OE)
Ù   Uppercase Accent Grave (U)
Û   Uppercase Accent Circonflex (U)
Ü   Uppercase Accent Tréma (U)
à   Lowercase Accent Grave (a)
â   Lowercase Accent Circonflex (a)
ä   Lowercase Accent Tréma (a)
æ   Lowercase Ligature(ae)
ç   Lowercase Cedilla (c)
```

For example for Italian (my mother tongue) the accent can be easy convert in this way:

```
  à = a'
  è = e'
  ì = i'
  ò = o'
  ù = u'
```

How ask if there is an easy way to do the some for the other languages.

Thanks !

Comment: "I can't use utf-8 but only ansi" **why**? The whole point of Unicode is to prevent people from having to do what you're trying to do, because what you're trying to do is hideously error-prone and cannot work in all scenarios. This question feels like an X-Y problem.

Comment: Seems similar to "transliteration" though the latter tends to just suppress the accents. Here is a [C# port](https://github.com/thecoderok/Unidecode.NET) of a Perl library.

Answer (score 1):

Only way I can think is to do manula mapping.

I would define some kind of mapper, which, based on the language would return "normalized to ANSI" character (so country specific UTF8 character would become ANSI character).

Here's a draft what I am talking about:

```
public static class CountrySpecificMapper
{
    private static Dictionary<char, string> _frenchDict = new Dictionary<char, string>()
    {
        {'À',"A"},
        {'Â',"A"},
        {'Ä',"A"},
        {'Æ',"AE"},
        {'Ç',"C"},
        {'È',"E"},
        {'É',"E"},
        {'Ê',"E"},
        {'Ë',"E"},
        {'Î',"I"},
        {'Ï',"I"},
        {'Ô',"O"},
        {'Œ',"OE"},
        {'Ù',"U"},
        {'Û',"U"},
        {'Ü',"U"},
        {'à',"a"},
        {'â',"a"},
        {'ä',"a"},
        {'æ',"ae"},
        {'ç',"c"} ,
    };

    private static Dictionary<char, string> _germanDict = new Dictionary<char, string>()
    {
        {'Ä', "A"},
        {'Ö', "O"},
        {'Ü', "U"},
        {'ß', "ss"},
        {'ä', "a"},
        {'ö', "o"},
        {'ü', "u"},
    };

    private static Dictionary<CultureInfo, Dictionary<char, string>> _langToDict = new Dictionary<CultureInfo, Dictionary<char, string>>()
    {
        {new CultureInfo("fr"), _frenchDict },
        {new CultureInfo("de"), _germanDict },
    };

    public static string MapCharacter(char @char, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (cultureInfo is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cultureInfo));

        var dict = _langToDict[cultureInfo];
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(@char))
        {
            // error or other validation
        }
        return dict[@char];
    }
}
```

Obviously, `CultureInfo` is rference type, so it is not good candidate for dictionary key used in internal implementation of a API (outer code will create own object of that class for the same culture, but reference address will differ..).

IT IS ONLY FOR PRESENTATION PURPOSE.

You can maybe rely on `LCID` property of `CultureInfo`, or define own keys, more suitable for your solution.

After all that work is done, converting diacritic characters are as simple as

```
var convertedChar = CountrySpecificMapper.MapCharacter(charToConvert, languageKey);
```